# OWIN service is not visible from network

Tags: c#

I created C# console application using `OWIN` and I have issue with visibility of application outside of localhost. For example if I made POST request with localhost in URL everything works fine, but when I replace URL in postman to my global IP address it stopped working. Port is opened, I can ping server from external computer. Earlier application based on IIS worked fine on this port with this global ip adress and port.

```
_webApp = WebApp.Start<StartOwin>("http://localhost:8511");
```

Line above should contains my global IP or it can be localhost with specific port?

Full code:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            return (int)HostFactory.Run(x =>
            {
                x.StartAutomatically();
                x.Service<OwinService>(s =>
                {
                    s.ConstructUsing(() => new OwinService());
                    s.WhenStarted(service => service.Start());
                    s.WhenStopped(service => service.Stop());
                });
            });
        }
    }

    public class OwinService
    {
        private IDisposable _webApp;

        public void Start()
        {
            _webApp = WebApp.Start<StartOwin>("http://localhost:8511");
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _webApp.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public class StartOwin
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
```

**#UPDATE**
I have changed port for application to 8512, fully unlocked this port and made following POST requests:

- http://localhost:8512 works fine
- http://127.0.0.1:8512 doesn't work
- http://my_global_address:8512 doesn't work

**#UPDATE2**

After setting 
`_webApp = WebApp.Start<StartOwin>("http://*:8511");`
and **turning off whole firewall** it works as expected, so it's network issue (serverfault.com)

**SOLUTION**

`_webApp = WebApp.Start<StartOwin>("http://*:8511");`
and add new firewall rule (allow inbound) for executable of this application

Comment: Did you check your firewall settings?

Comment: @SteveB Yes, I have unlocked TCP port 8511 for all programs

Comment: `The request hostname is invalid`: this does not seem to be a network isse, but more a format issue. Can you show us what is the exact address you are trying to connect to ? Maybe there's a typo ?

Comment: If you host it on `localhost`, you're using the loopback address.  It has to have a real host name or IP to work.

Comment: TopShelf has nothing to do with your question. TopShelf is merely a wrapper around a program to make it able to be hosted by a Windows service, it has nothing to do with Owin hosting.

Comment: @Amy after chaning localhost to my external IP adress in code I've got error during application start `The service failed to start., System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException`

Comment: You must start it on an IP address assigned to the system, not an external IP.

Comment: @Amy Do you mean my private address? It doesn't work

Comment: "it doesn't work" doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: @Amy when I put my private address into code and made POST request with external address I get message "Could not get any response" in postman. It only works for private address in request

Comment: Is your external address mapped to the internal address? Or is the client on the same subnet?

Comment: ... mkul, you have to map the port from the external gateway to your private address.  You can't bind directly to an external address.

Comment: @Amy Actual firewall and IP config works fine with applications on IIS, so why I must change my network settings? On the other hand I don't know how do this... (map the port from the external gateway to my private address)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's actually a networking issue, not a programming one.  As such, it belongs on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Do you have any idea what Network Address Translation is? Requests come to your router via an external IP. Those requests have to be mapped to a specific internal IP address within your network so that they know where to go. It's like showing up to an apartment complex to deliver a package, but not knowing what apartment number is the correct one to deliver the package to. This is basic network stuff, and I agree with Amy. You're better served by researching NAT and port mapping and asking on serverfault.com.

Comment: You are right, I realized that after turning off whole firewall it works as expected, so I'm going to search solution on serverfault. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
_webApp = WebApp.Start<StartOwin>("http://*:8511");
```

Don't worry about the specific IP or hostname. Just bind it to "any" using the above.

Comment: It works for localhost, 127.0.0.1, my private address, machine name, but it's **not** working for external ip adress

Comment: You can't bind to an external address, only one that the system has assigned to it.

Comment: This solutions works fine when I turned off whole firewall

Comment: Seems you're trying to solve two different problems. Exposing this OWIN Application to the outside, AND routing your external IP to this specific server.